# Optimizing Cuda Execution Configuration

Tags: cuda, gpu

I’m trying to learn Cuda in order to speed up the resolution of some stochastic systems of differential equations for my PhD.

I will be using A100 gpus, which have 128 SM each with 64K registers and 164KB of shared memory. I will be referring to those as memory ressources (not sure if I also should have other things in mind when talking about ressources).

---

First, I have a general question concerning the best Cuda Execution Configuration.

I have been reading the book Professional Cuda Programming by Cheng, Grossman and McKercher in which they state:
“Avoid small block sizes: Start with at least 128 or 256 threads per block”  and  “Keep the number of blocks much greater than the number of SMs to expose sufficient parallelism to your device”.

The first sentence obviously refers to the need for enough warps on a SM to keep good occupancy in order to hide latencies.
However, I would like to validate my understanding of the second sentence. Is the following way of thinking correct:

Assume I have a streaming multiprocessor that has enough memory ressources for 2048 of my threads to run concurrently. This means I’m able to use threads that use less than 64K/2048 registers and 164KB/2048 of shared memory.
Since 2048 threads also corresponds to the maximum amount of warps per SM, I can assume that occupancy is high enough.

So what is the difference between having 4 blocks of 512 threads and 2 blocks with 1024 threads for the SM? In both cases I have the same number of warps soo those two approaches expose the SM to the same level of parallelism right?

Similarly if I only have enough ressources for 1024 threads, there is actually no difference between 1 block of 1024 threads, 2 blocks of 512 and 4 blocks of 256 threads. In this case I will just need twice the number of SM to run 2048 threads (threads using the same memory ressources).

When there is a possible difference, is when the ressources limit the number of threads that can run concurrently on a SM below the MAX number of threads per block. For example, assume there is only enough memory ressources for 256 threads.  Now , 4 blocks of 256 threads is obviously much better than 2 of 512 threads because they can be spread over more SM to expose more parallelism.
So it is the limited amount of ressources which favors increasing the number of blocks? Is that how I should understand this sentence?

If this is true, the way to expose the most parallelism, is to minimize the number of ressources needed per thread, or subdivide the program in smaller independent threads when reasonable.

---

Now suppose that based on the application we can determine the ideal thread size we can work with.

Based on the available memory ressources we then have determined that we want X threads to run on each SM, separated in Y number of blocks in order to have good occupancy.

Using the Cuda Execution Configuration we can only give to Cuda a number of blocks and a number of threads per blocks. So should we expect <<<128*Y, X>>> to do what I described?

To make it concrete, let’s assume we calculate that the memory ressources allow us to have 256 independent threads on a single SM. Therefore, we want 1 block of 256 threads to run on a single SM. Then we would choose a grid dimension of 128 or more and a block dimension of 256 threads  (X=256, Y=1+).

Is this way of thinking correct?

Comment: If the number of blocks is less than the number of SMs, than there is no possibility that all SMs can be used. There are about two general performance reasons to choose a greater number: 1) If it is possible to run more than one block per SM due to significantly low "memory resource" requirements (as in your examples); 2) If some of your blocks have a much shorter or longer execution time than others, those differences can be better hidden, if there is enough additional work to do for the SMs with finished kernels.

Comment: If your threads have no interdependencies and no synchronization to do, it does not matter, whether your configuration is 4*512 or 2*1024. But: There is a maximum number of concurrent blocks per SM. And your block size should be a multiple of 32 or - if not possible - be a high number to reduce the wasted threads. Even if you do not have interdependencies for your computation, it can make sense to let the threads cooperate for better memory accesses (coalescing) and manual (shared memory) or automatic (L1) caching.

Comment: @Sebastian, thank you, those are good points. Furthermore, I also realized that sometimes there may also be limitations on the shared memory allowed per block too, which would also suggest to work with smaller blocks.

Answer (score 2):

> A100 gpus, which have 128 SM

A100 GPUs have 108 SMs.  The A100 die has 128 SMs possible, but not all 128 are exposed in any actual product.

> So what is the difference between having 4 blocks of 512 threads and 2 blocks with 1024 threads for the SM? In both cases I have the same number of warps so those two approaches expose the SM to the same level of parallelism right?

Yes, given your stipulations (max occupancy = 2048 threads/SM).

> For example, assume there is only enough memory resources for 256 threads. Now , 4 blocks of 256 threads is obviously much better than 2 of 512 threads because they can be spread over more SM to expose more parallelism. So it is the limited amount of ressources which favors increasing the number of blocks? Is that how I should understand this sentence?

Given your stipulation ("only enough memory resources for 256 threads"), the case of two threadblocks of 512 threads would **fail to launch**.  However, for these very small grid sizes, 8 blocks of 128 threads might be better than 4 blocks of 256 threads, because 8 blocks of 128 threads could conceivably bring 8 SMs to bear on the problem (depending on your GPU), whereas 4 blocks of 256 threads could only bring 4 SMs to bear on the problem.

> To make it concrete, let’s assume we calculate that the memory resources allow us to have 256 independent threads on a single SM. Therefore, we want 1 block of 256 threads to run on a single SM. Then we would choose a grid dimension of 128 or more and a block dimension of 256 threads (X=256, Y=1+).

Yes, if your GPU has 108 SMs, then grid sizing choices of 108 * N where N is a positive integer would probably be sensible/reasonable, for the number of blocks.  For N of 2 or larger, this would also tend to satisfy the 2nd statement given in the book:

> “Keep the number of blocks much greater than the number of SMs to expose sufficient parallelism to your device”.

(This statement is a general statement, and is not advanced with a particular limit on block size or threads per SM in mind. If you truly have a limit due to code design of 256 threads per SM, and your threadblock size is 256, then N = 1 should be sufficient for "full occupancy".)

Kernel designs using a [grid stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) will often give you the flexibility to choose grid size independently of problem size.

Comment: I see thank you, many of your answers to other posts have helped me too.

Comment: May I also ask where could I find more informations about GPU architecture, such as the number of SMs each model has and how they are organized? It's not in the Cuda toolkit documentation as far as I can see

Comment: The best architectural treatments are found in the whitepapers.  These are easy to find with a google search.  For other GPUs, I generally use google.  There are extensive lists of GPU specs, such as techpowerup.com.  Finally, there are fairly extensive lists on wikipedia.  Overall, google is your friend.